# Why doesn't this jQuery AJAX work?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, form-submit

I don't understand why this form wont send.

The coding is very long and I don't think it would be good idea to post all of it here.

- Link to form [here](https://www.mylittleextra.com/multiform/)
- Link to Script [here](https://www.mylittleextra.com/multiform/js/jquery.main.js)

  *I just tried loading the PHP file in browser and it wouldn't work.  I will save it as a .txt file so you can view it.  It will be @ ......multiform/post.txt*

On top of that, how would I send the entire form instead of stating all the values for the 'data' bit:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: {subject:options.subject, name:$(this_id_prefix+'#adycustlname').val(),     email:$(this_id_prefix+'#email').val(), message:$(this_id_prefix+'#zip').val()},
        success: function(data){
```

Also ignore the `success: function(data){` section, this form is going to be put in a slide panel so that is for what the slider should do after.  I have a feeling it is wrong, but
the main issue is to get the form to send.

**EDIT**

```
     $('#submit_seventh').click(function(){

               //send information to server

       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post.php',
            data: $('#bob').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                        $(this_id_prefix+'#loading').css({display:'none'}); 
                        if( data == 'success') {
                            $(this_id_prefix+'#callback').show().append(options.recievedMsg);
                            if(options.hideOnSubmit == true) {
                                //hide the tab after successful submition if requested
                                $(this_id_prefix+'#contactForm').animate({dummy:1}, 2000).animate({"marginLeft": "-=450px"}, "slow");
                                $(this_id_prefix+'div#contactable_inner').animate({dummy:1}, 2000).animate({"marginLeft": "-=447px"}, "slow").animate({"marginLeft": "+=5px"}, "fast"); 
                                $(this_id_prefix+'#overlay').css({display: 'none'});    
                            }
                        } else {
                            $(this_id_prefix+'#callback').show().append(options.notRecievedMsg);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                $(this_id_prefix+'.holder').show();
                                $(this_id_prefix+'#callback').hide().html('');
                            },2000);
                        }
                    },
  error:function(){
                        $(this_id_prefix+'#loading').css({display:'none'}); 
                        $(this_id_prefix+'#callback').show().append(options.notRecievedMsg);
                                        }
});     




        alert('Data sent');
    });   
        } else return false;  
        alert('Fail');

    });
```

^^^^^ Why wont the above code work? ^^^^^

Comment: Can you sort out relevant code and put it here? It's too long to read

Comment: `data: $('#yourform').serialize()` will capture all of the form's data.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes  @Marc B , ive added the change to `data:` also i've added the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your script you have to replace

```
$('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
    //send information to server
    alert('Data sent');
});
```

with the correct URL to send to.

Comment: @powtac @dm03514 i dont get it, do i add the `$.ajax` or not?.. + the submit happens on `$('#submit_seventh').click....`